# How to send unsigned values to dBus from Python

Tags: python, qt5, dbus, qtdbus

I'm trying to use PyQt5's DBus module to interact with the KDE PowerManagerAgent. When calling the AddInhibition method I need to send the first paramter as an uint32 (Unsigned int), but the code sends the value as a singed int.

The code is written using Python 3

```
self.dBus = QtDBus.QDBusConnection.sessionBus()
msg = QtDBus.QDBusMessage.createMethodCall(self.dBusService, self.dBusPath,self.dBusInterface,'AddInhibition')
msg << 1 << who << reason
reply = QtDBus.QDBusReply(self.dBus.call(msg))
```

Looking at the output from dbus-monitor I can tell that the code does indeed contact the powermonitor but fails to find the correct AddInhibition method due to the first parameter being type as int32

## Output from dbus-monitor when trying to call AddInhibition

### Call

method call time=1549706946.073218 sender=:1.172 -> destination=org.kde.Solid.PowerManagement.PolicyAgent serial=5 path=/org/kde/Solid/PowerManagement/PolicyAgent; interface=org.kde.Solid.PowerManagement.PolicyAgent; member=AddInhibition
   **int32 1**
   string "This"
   string "fails"

### Reply

error time=1549706946.073536 sender=:1.29 -> destination=:1.172 error_name=org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod reply_serial=5
   string "No such method 'AddInhibition' in interface 'org.kde.Solid.PowerManagement.PolicyAgent' at object path '/org/kde/Solid/PowerManagement/PolicyAgent' (signature 'iss')"

## Output from dbus-monitor when using QDBusViewer application

### Call

method call time=1549723045.320128 sender=:1.82 -> destination=org.kde.Solid.PowerManagement.PolicyAgent serial=177 path=/org/kde/Solid/PowerManagement/PolicyAgent; interface=org.kde.Solid.PowerManagement.PolicyAgent; member=AddInhibition
   **uint32 1**
   string "This"
   string "Works"

### Reply

method return time=1549723045.320888 sender=:1.29 -> destination=:1.82 serial=1370 reply_serial=177
   uint32 30

Since Python is not strongly typed how do I specify the the parameter must be typed as an unsigned int?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `DBusArgument` class to do this by specifying the `QMetaType` of the argument.

For example, say you want to use the `RequestName` method from `org.freedesktop.DBus` (see [the spec](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html)). The `flags` argument is an unsigned int, so you'll run into this problem:

```
>>> from PyQt5.QtDBus import QDBusConnection, QDBusInterface
>>> sessionbus = QDBusConnection.sessionBus()
>>> iface = QDBusInterface("org.freedesktop.DBus", "/org/freedesktop/DBus", "org.freedesktop.DBus", sessionbus)
>>> c = iface.call('RequestName', 'com.mydomain.myapp', 4)
>>> c.arguments()
['Call to RequestName has wrong args (si, expected su)\n']
```

So, it's saying it got a string and an integer (`si`), but it wanted a string and an unsigned integer (`su`). So, we'll use the `QDBusArgument` class and specify `QMetaType.UInt`:

```
>>> from PyQt5.QtCore import QMetaType
>>> from PyQt5.QtDBus import QDBusConnection, QDBusInterface, QDBusArgument
>>> sessionbus = QDBusConnection.sessionBus()
>>> iface = QDBusInterface("org.freedesktop.DBus", "/org/freedesktop/DBus", "org.freedesktop.DBus", sessionbus)
>>> a1 = QDBusArgument()
>>> a1.add('com.mydomain.myapp', QMetaType.QString)
>>> a2 = QDBusArgument(4, QMetaType.UInt)
>>> c = iface.call('RequestName', a1, a2)
>>> c.arguments()
[1]
```

Since the string was fine, that didn't have to be a `QDBusArgument`. I just wanted to show the two ways of constructing it (with the `.add()` method and just using the constructor).